# Implement security only at ZUUL Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

I have the below microservice architecture(spring boot ,java). I want to implement  OAUTH2 JWT security at ZUUL gateway only and  not replicate the security code in microservices .
let say Microservice 1 has rest end point http://localhost:8080/microservice-1/get/person then i should not have any security code in Microservice 1 but still  at the same time no one should be able to access the Microservice 1 rest end point directly without passing JWT tokens but it should only be accessible via ZUUL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class in your Zuul gateway and configure the security for each route.

This is an excellent example for you

https://medium.com/@bharatrajmeriyala/spring-cloud-security-with-netflix-zuul-2ef04a1dcfb